# Devise redirect upon sign based on flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

We have recently introduced a new boolean attribute called `toc_accepted` in our user model which would be `false` by default. If the Devise `active_for_authentication?` is true and this attributes is false, we should not allow the user to sign in. Instead they have to be redirected to a page where they can read and accept the Terms of service. How can I accomplish this?

Note that, the redirect should happen only if the user is eligible to login and `toc_accepted` is false. In all other cases, we should follow the usual procedure.

Comment: Do you actually want them to not be signed in if they haven't accepted the terms of service? That is, after they accept the terms, they're still logged out and have to enter their username/password again to get signed in? Or do you just want to make sure they get sent to the terms of service page after logging in if they haven't accepted the terms? If that's the case, I'm assuming you'd want a redirect to the terms if they try to go to other pages too?

Comment: If the login credentials are correct, the user should be navigated to toc page without logging in. They will again be redirected to sign in page to re-enter the login details once the  terms are accepted.

Comment: OK. I don't understand why you'd make the user enter their credentials twice (you know who they are already), but there must be some reason. How are you going to know which user accepted the terms? They'll be signed out, so you won't have an active user session to associate them with.

Comment: But if this is what you want to do, you can overwrite `active_for_authentication?` in your model, defining it as `super && toc_accepted` or something similar. Are you asking how to make it redirect to the TOC page when that happens?

Comment: Thanks @Max. Let me try it out. I can make use of session variables for identifying which user is accepting the terms. For maintaining the session even after calling `sign_out` helper method, I've overridden `sign_out` method.

Answer (score 0):

The `sessions_controller` can be overriddein in your `routes.rb`.

```
devise_for 'Myapp::V1::System::User', at: 'myapp/v1/system/auth/sign_in', controllers: {
      sessions: 'myapp/v1/system/overrides/sessions'
    }
```

In sessions_controller, you can check whether user has accepted the ToC.

```
  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    # Let's check for ToC Accept
    check_for_toc_accept()

    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
```